# getWritableDatabase causes nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I am working on a project using a Database that stores specific information.  The database works for part of the program, but yet for others it does not.  When the user first starts the program they will see information this is pulled from the db, and they also have the option to add new information.  The db works fine for both of these.

What I am having issues with is at another spot of adding information.  When I go to open the db, my program crashes.
LOGCAT:

```
08-29 20:22:47.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 20:22:47.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3022): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 20:22:47.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3022):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
08-29 20:22:47.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3022):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper._getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
08-29 20:22:47.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3022):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:100)
08-29 20:22:47.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3022):     at peices.DbM.open(DbM.java:173)
08-29 20:22:47.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3022):     at peices.NewStuff.CreateNewUnit(NewStuff.java:27)
08-29 20:22:47.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3022):     at carlson.msum.arch.Site$5.onClick(Site.java:231)
08-29 20:22:47.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3022):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
```

Code for NewStuff:27(Lines 20-30):

```
bb=Lon.getText().toString();
            cc=UnitName.getText().toString();
            Log.d("Class",aa);
            Log.d("Class",bb);
            Log.d("Class",cc);
            Log.d("Class",SiteName);
            Log.d("Stuff","Before Open");
            **db.open();**
            Log.d("Stuff","Before Insert/After Open");
            db.InsertUnit(SiteName, cc, aa, bb);
            Log.d("Stuff","Before Close/After Insert");
            db.close();
```

Code for DbM.java:173(170-176)

```
public DbM open() throws SQLException
{
    Log.d("BmDb","open");
    **db= DbMh.getWritableDatabase();**
    Log.d("BmDb","Open before return");
    return this;
}
```

I already know it has somthing to do with the opening of the db, but why would it open and work for other activities, but not this one?  I checked out and all activities that would be before this one, and I did close all of the db's.

this is the start of the class, the DbM initialization is how I do it for all the others.

```
public class NewStuff extends Activity {
Context context;
**DbM db=new DbM(this);**
```

One thing it could be, but not sure how to fix it is that this is a class of objects that I am using in other parts of the program.  So I am not calling any oncreates or anything like that, would that be causing my issue?

****EDIT****

This is my entire NewStuff class, I must be missing somthing else other then just the context because nothing seems to work.

```
package peices;
import peices.DbM;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class NewStuff extends Activity {
Context context;
DbM db;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db=new DbM(this);
        }
    public void CreateNewUnit(EditText Lat, EditText Lon, EditText UnitName, String SiteName)
    {

            db=new DbM(this);
            Log.d("NewUnit","Start of");
            String aa="";
            String bb="";
            String cc="";

            aa=Lat.getText().toString();
            bb=Lon.getText().toString();
            cc=UnitName.getText().toString();
            Log.d("Class",aa);
            Log.d("Class",bb);
            Log.d("Class",cc);
            Log.d("Class",SiteName);
            Log.d("Stuff","Before Open");
            db.open();
            Log.d("Stuff","Before Insert/After Open");
            db.InsertUnit(SiteName, cc, aa, bb);
            Log.d("Stuff","Before Close/After Insert");
            db.close();     
    }
```

***EDIT***

The onclick function that calls NewStuff

```
ucreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View m){
            Log.d("Ubox","Unit Name: "+uname.getText().toString());
            Log.d("Ubox","Unit Longitude: "+ulon.getText().toString());
            Log.d("Ubox","Unit Latitude: "+ulat.getText().toString());
            Log.d("Ubox","Site Name: "+SiteName);
            NewStuff ns= new NewStuff();
            ns.CreateNewUnit(ulat,ulon,uname,SiteName);
            Intent I= new Intent(Site.this, Site.class);
            I.putExtra("SITE", SiteName);
            startActivity(I);
```

Comment: I know I have them outside the OnCreate, but I am using these as functions to call inside another class.  Maybe I am doing that wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize DbM as a field, Since the Context would not have been initialized

```
 DbM db=new DbM(this);
```

Call

```
 db=new DbM(this);
```

only in or after OnCreate.

Edit:
You cannot call

```
NewStuff ns= new NewStuff()
```

This is because if you instantiate yourself , the context for the activity will not be set. So `this` inside **new DbM(this);**  will have no meaning.

Mainly you should not usually call a function an activity from another Activity.

Comment: My appologies, but I am not following your answer.  When I try db=new DbM(this); I now am getting a VariableDeclaratorId, which means it is not finding the variable for it.  Am I missing somthing here?

Comment: can you show the Onclick function are you initiating the class NewStuff with new call?

Comment: I placed the onclick function that calls the newstuff in my original post.

Comment: Ok, I get what you were saying now.  Unfortunately what I wanted to do, like you said I shouldn't do.  What I was trying to do was probably more on the lines of a library, but I would have to look at that some more to determine if that is in deed what I would want.

Answer (score 1):

Define db this way

```
public class NewStuff extends Activity {
Context context;
DbM db;
```

then onCreate(

```
onCreate(){
........
   db=new DbM(this); 
}
```

Thats what @nandeesh is trying to tell you.

Comment: ok, I understand what you are suggesting.  However nothing seems to work.  Your suggestion actually does not even get to my db, it makes db.open a nullpointer.  I have been trying all sorts of things for the past hour+.  So I am going to edit my initial post with my entire NewStuff class, it has to be something else that I did wrong.

Comment: Yeah having the whole code will help. Maybe you forgot to close you db somewhere.